# Recover pre-installed ruby to Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos

I know it should never be done, but I accidentally removed the folder /usr/bin/ruby from my Mac OS X. With that I lost all pre-installed ruby files. Now when trying to install Homebrew, for instance, I get the error:

> -bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

How can I get pre-installed ruby back to /usr/bin?

Comment: Well hopefully you have a backup? If not I suppose you'll have to reinstall to get the Apple provided Ruby back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install [rvm](https://rvm.io//) and get most updated ruby. Even because the one shipped with OS X is rather obsolete (it should be 1.8.7 if I remember correctly).

There's no need to reinstall the bundled one when you can install an updated version in just a couple of minutes.

Comment: how are you sure there is no need to re-install the system ruby? what about xcode or osx apps that rely on ruby, won't they try run ruby from the default location?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just download it from: ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.6-p111.tar.bz2

and then compile it into your /usr/bin directory.

There still might be permission/ownership  issues you'd have to deal with.

Comment: Installing it as root using sudo, or using chmod, chown as needed.